# Search value in firebase realtime on button click

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I have been searching on how to do this and most of the answers are searching by filtering the words. What i wanted is searching on button click and display the results on next activity. This is how my search look like :

[image]

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_student;

    mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);


    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mchildref = mDbref.child("Students");
            Query query = mchildref.orderByChild("Name").equalTo(search);

            mchildref.child("Students").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Intent search= new Intent(SearchStudentActivity.this, testing.class);
                    startActivity(search);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Hope to learn from you guys and thanks.

Comment: Please post what you want to search. is it specific field data or something ?

Comment: Realtime is to update data instantly, you better use Firestore

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @Ashish Find string that is on input field.

Comment: @JamaldinSabirjanov When i click search, it gives me blank page.

Comment: @SarahMiller I've posted an answer you can check it now. I have modified the method a bit. Let me know if you need any explanation regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_student;

    mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    //Add a TextView here to set the text (optional, depends on how you want to show the retrieved data)
    String lastName;

    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        final String studentToSearch = search.getText().toString();

        myDbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students").child(studentToSearch);
        myDbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                lastName = dataSnapshot.child("last name").getValue().toString();
                lastNameTextView.setText(lastName);
            }catch (Throwable e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Please try it this way. Here I assumed that you have a child node called "last name" inside the parent node like this `Students >> studentToSearch >> last name`.
Just replace anything instead of last name to fetch other information.

Comment: Yes it works thanks, i add also addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: @SarahMiller nice to hear it works for you. If you feel this is correct answer, please accept it as the answer by clicking the TICK icon and upvote if you like it. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

One solution to replace your `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` with `ValueEventListener`.

Attaching a `ValueEventListener` to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single DataSnapshot, which you can then loop over to access individual children.

```
        Query query = mchildref.orderByChild("Name").equalTo(search);

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              // TODO: handle the post, extract the values to pass to another activity
            }

            String value =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Intent search= new Intent(SearchStudentActivity.this, testing.class);
            startActivity(search);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
        });

//        mchildref.child("Students").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//            String value =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
//            Intent search= new Intent(SearchStudentActivity.this, testing.class);
//            startActivity(search);
//
//          }
```